# lucene phrase exact search

Tags: java, hibernate, search, lucene, hibernate-search

I am using phrase query for hibernate lucene search in my code.It is working but I want to do exact search which is case Insensitive.I have tried term query but it is case sensitive.
I want to search like eg:

BeautifulRainy Day.
If I search "rainy day" the result should be 0 hits.
If i search "beautifulrainy Day" the result should be 1 hit.
If I search "Day" the result should be 0 hits.

Basically I want java (.equalignorecase ) type search not (.contains) .I want to keep using the phrase query if it is possible.

Answer (score 0):

If you want case-insensitive matching, you have to index your data case-insensitive.

You can do this by, for example, adding another field to your class with the `toLowerCase()` value of your String and search that field instead.

(Or maybe hibernate search allows case-insensitive indexing with a option?)

Answer (score 0):

Hi Please go through this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37495639/how-to-match-exact-text-in-lucene-search/37502386#37502386) given by me. which search exact case insensitive term. Have just passed the search string in double quotes which act as exact match search.

```
QueryParser parser = new QueryParser(Version.LUCENE_34, "TITLE" ,new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_34));

    Query query;

    query = parser.parse("\"beautifulrainy Day\"");

    TopDocs hits = searcher.search(query,3);
```

Here `TITLE` is the name of the field, so place field name which you have used at the time of indexing.